# Atomic operations with Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I can't seem to get the following query to work. Basically, I am trying to add a message document to a conversation document as illustrated below:

```php
public function reply($conversationId, Message $message, $flush = true)
{            
    $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->class)
        ->field('archivers')->unsetField()
        ->field('repliedBy')->set($message->getUserId())
        ->field('repliedBody')->set($message->getBody())
        ->field('repliedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('modifiedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('messages')->push($message)
        ->field('id')->equals(new \MongoId($conversationId))
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    if ($flush) {
        $this->dm->flush();
    }
}
```

This reply method gets called in two ways. First by a user posting a message via a html form, and second by a REST call made by an Android application. The form works but the REST call fails (the rest implementation uses the JMSSerializerBundle with FOSRestBundle btw)...

I have verified that the code gets called and the parameters passed to the method are valid in both cases, but for some reason the commit() call inside UnitOfWork.php ignores the changes to the document. See [line 413](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php#L413) to see what I mean.

Does anybody have an idea why this might be happening?

Below are the other approaches that I have tried:

First, I added an update() call which fails with "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class ... could not be converted to string in /vendor/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/Logger/DoctrineMongoDBLogger.php line 280".

```php
public function reply($conversationId, Message $message, $flush = true)
{            
    $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->class)
        ->update()
        ->field('archivers')->unsetField()
        ->field('repliedBy')->set($message->getUserId())
        ->field('repliedBody')->set($message->getBody())
        ->field('repliedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('modifiedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('messages')->push($message)
        ->field('id')->equals(new \MongoId($conversationId))
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    if ($flush) {
        $this->dm->flush();
    }
}
```

Second approach I tried was pushing an array instead of an object:

```php
public function reply($conversationId, Message $message)
{            
    $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->class)
        ->update()
        ->field('archivers')->unsetField()
        ->field('repliedBy')->set($message->getUserId())
        ->field('repliedBody')->set($message->getBody())
        ->field('repliedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('modifiedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('messages')->push(array(
            '_id' => new \MongoId(),
            'userId' => $message->getuserId(),
            'body' => $message->getBody(),
            'createdAt' => new \DateTime(),
            'modifiedAt' => new \DateTime(),
        ))
        ->field('id')->equals(new \MongoId($conversationId))
        ->getQuery() 
        ->execute();

    $this->dm->flush();
}
```

Which works fine until the flush() method gets called. The flush() causes duplicate objects to be pushed. So I get two copies of the same message in the conversation (commenting the flush() solves the issue but the application has multiple flush() calls in other classes).

Another push query that fails with an object:

```php
public function archive($conversationId, $userId)
{

    $userStamp = new UserStamp();
    $userStamp->setUserId($userId);

    $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->class)
        ->update()
        ->field('archivers')->push($userStamp)
        ->field('modifiedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('id')->equals(new \MongoId($conversationId))
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

If the push() call is removed, everything works fine.

Still stuck at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query builder is typically used to execute multi-document or command queries against MongoDB, which bypass document management. The only exception is if you are performing a hydrated find query, which is described in the [query builder documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#disabling-hydration). Your example above is equivalent to:

```
$collection->update(
    ['_id' => new \MongoId($conversationId)],
    [
        '$set' => [
            'repliedBy' => $message->getUserId(),
            'repliedBody' => $message->getbody(),
            'repliedAt' => new \MongoDate(),
            'modifiedAt' => new \MongoDate(),
        ],
        '$push' => ['messages' => $message],
    ],
    ['multiple' => false]
);
```

Note that your field mappings will be utilized (e.g. Datetime will become a MongoDate), but there is no document to manage with this query.

Comment: Hi @jmikola, I am confused. The documentation clearly has a [section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#update-queries) dedicated for atomic updates.

Besides, my initial query works fine as long as the call comes from a web browser. That is what I am baffled about.

Comment: I have also added a couple of other approaches I tried to my original post; however, all of them fail for one reason or another.

Can the push() method be used to push objects instead of simple types at all? Do I have to add the update() call to my queries? If so, why does my first query work without it (at least in certain instances) and fail with it?

Comment: I missed it in your original code example, but you do need to call `update()` when building the query. Without that, it will default to a `find()`. That could explain some of the odd behavior you're seeing, since `find()` may end up hydrating the returned object; however, none of the set/push operators will be used. As for `push()`, its argument gets passed as-is to the driver. I believe the standard behavior for objects is that only *public* properties are read, which likely doesn't work for you. Converting to an array would be advisable.

Comment: Thanks, your sentence about push() capabilities explains a lot. 

I have a couple of other questions if you don't mind. Am I supposed to call flush() for update queries (it seems to work without it)? In addition, do you have any idea why the code is pushing two identical messages to the conversation when I call flush and only one when I simply comment it out?

Comment: Figured out the duplicate issue. Turns out when you retrieve a document via the query builder and make updates to it, it gets flushed to MongoDB even if persist() is not called on that document. This is because that document is a managed document. See [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-documents)

Comment: Thanks for the push() explanation; it definitely helped me in the right direction. It would definitely be a cool feature to be able to push embedded documents. Manually implementing callback functionality (setting createdAt, modofiedAt dates for example) becomes necessary otherwise.

Comment: Re: the duplication, that's what I alluded to in the second sentence of the original answer. The only time the query builder interacts with the document manager is when you're doing a find query *with hydration*. Then, the result is converted into a managed document. `persist()` only serves to tell the DM to start managing a document -- it should do nothing for documents that are already managed.

Comment: Re: your last question about `push()`, you can achieve that behavior by working with the managed document and pushing your object onto EmbedMany-mapped field, which should be a Collection instance. Both ReferenceMany and EmbedMany fields should be initialized as ArrayCollections (instead of basic arrays) in your constructors. When ODM hydrates the document (e.g. after a find query), those fields will be PersistentCollection instances (same interface), and new/removed references/objects will be pushed/pulled. Additionally, lifecycle events will trigger (for things like timestamp changes).

Comment: Would that be atomic? What happens if the other user in the conversation replies? Do I need to retry the query if the document is not current?

Adding a message document to an ArrayCollection is actually the methodology that I use when creating a new conversation. When replying to an existing conversation however, I decided to use the push() method specifically as multiple users may be replying at the same time and I don't want to retry the query. Or maybe I am completely wrong and Doctrine ODM uses atomic operators instead of replacing the entire document for updates?

Comment: Adding an embedded document to a PersistentCollection should result in a `$push` operation. If you were to change a single field within an embedded document within a PersistentCollection, that should result in a `$set` on that field (I believe the array offset would appear in the field name). If you enable query logging, you can watch what ODM does as you modify and flush persistent objects.

Answer (score 0):

If pushing an object durring an update use \stdClass in php. 
quick example:

```
public function reply($conversationId, Message $message)
{      
       $object = new \stdClass();
       $object->_id = new \MongoId();
       $object->userId = $message->getuserId();
       $object->body = $message->getBody();
       $object->createdAt = new \MongoDate();
       $object->modifiedAt = new \MongoDate();

       $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->class)
        ->update()
        ->field('archivers')->unsetField()
        ->field('repliedBy')->set($message->getUserId())
        ->field('repliedBody')->set($message->getBody())
        ->field('repliedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('modifiedAt')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('messages')->push()
        ->field('id')->equals(new \MongoId($conversationId))
        ->getQuery() 
        ->execute();

        $this->dm->flush();
}
```